# Async API using Spring + Jersey

Tags: spring, asynchronous, jersey, spring-boot

I am working on building API that could potentially have a high number of requests per second, and some of the requests may require a lot of computation (complex reports). I've been asked to put together a small prototype as proof of concept. I am using Spring Boot with Jersey as my JAX-RS implementation. In the past I've done something like this with Spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public DeferredResult<String> showDashboard(Model model) {
    DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    model.addAttribute("testObj", new User());
    result.setResult("home/dashboard");
    return result;
}
```

I tried this with Jersey and appears to work, or at least it didn't throw an error.

```
    @GET
    public DeferredResult<String> getClients() {
        DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        deferredResult.setResult("Nothing! But I'm Async!");
        return deferredResult;
    }
```

However all the examples I've seen for handling operations asynchronously in Jersey look like this.

```
Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public void get(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response) {
  // This call does not block.
  client.callExternalService(
    // This callback is invoked after the external service responds.
    new Callback<string>() {
      public void callback(String result) {
        response.resume("Result: " + result + ".n");
      }
    });
}
```

My main question is what is the difference between these three code snippets behind the scenes, if there even is any. Will these all accomplish the same thing?

Is there a better way to accomplish async? I've also seen the use of Future in Java, but never used it.

UPDATE:

I have the following code in my Jersey Controller which is all working.

```
    @GET
    public String getClients() {
        return "Nothing, I'm Sync!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/deferred")
    public DeferredResult<String> getClientsAsync() {
        DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        deferredResult.setResult("Nothing! But I'm Async!");
        return deferredResult;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/async")
    public void getClientsJAXRSAsync(@Suspended AsyncResponse response) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            response.resume("I am Async too! But I am using @Suspended");
        }).start();
    }
```

Which goes back to my main question, what is the difference between these? My understanding is DeferredResult is a Spring thing so not sure if its appropriate to use with Jersey, although I am using Jersey + Spring.

Comment: This is one of my posted question. Have a look at it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563475/null-pointer-exception-in-resteasy-asynchronous-request NOTE: I Still didn't test whether the proposed answer is working..

Comment: the " new Thread(() -> {" one. I thing it is not good. I would create more and more threads instead of reusing existing.

Answer (score -3):

Your understanding is quite right.Both are doing a same job.But implementations are different. DeferredResult is spring implementetion. And in your codebase most of the part is of JAX-RS implementation. I am not sure you are getting response from the fist service.

But my opinion is , either you use spring classes or JAX-RS. But not both in same method.

Comment: The first two methods are not Asynchronous, those may be asynchronous on the client side(based on type of request settings), but it's fully synchronous on the backend until the method completes its execution. The third method which the OP posted is an example of Real Server side Asynchronous processing..